# How do I make an AJAX request to an ASP.NET webform using $.getJSON?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

Using an example from a book that I have, I was able to successfully make an AJAX request to an ASP.NET webform using jQuery's $.ajax. However, I have not been successful in using $.getJSON, $.get, or $.post. Is it possible to use $.getJSON (or the other two for that matter) to make an AJAX request of a webform? If so, could you provide an example? The example that I used for $.ajax involved the usage of a static method in the code-behind file that was marked with the WebMethod attribute.

Here is some sample client-side code that works for me using $.ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Button4").click(function () {
            $.ajax({ type: "POST", dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json", url: "HelloWorld.aspx/GetInfo", data: "{}", success: function (result) {
                alert(result.d);
            }, error: function () { alert("error occurred"); } 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
<input id="Button4" type="button" value="Get Info" />
```

Here is the code-behind:

```
public partial class HellowWorld : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetInfo()
    {
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

One thing that may be useful to know is that the response header content type appears to be application/json when i use $.ajax. It is text/html when I use $.getJSON. It makes me think that I am missing a step for serialization into JSON.

Here's the sample call I was trying that didn't work:

```
$.getJSON("UpdatePanel.aspx/GetInfo", "{}", function (result) { alert(result.d); });
```

Comment: I recommend getting something like FireBug or using Chrome's developers' tools to monitor network requests and responses. jQuery ajax requests fail very gracefully, so it's useful to see what the server response was, even if jQuery discards it as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your `$.ajax` code.  `$.get()` and `$.post()` are just short forms of the `$.ajax()` function so chances are you are omitting a piece of information in those that is required and you had included in the `$.ajax()` call without realizing it.